# Only rotates in Z axis

Tags: objects

I'm trying to rotate my object but no matter which ring I click and drag, it only rotates in the Z axis. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Blender, and that doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to see your blend file.  Can you add it to your question? Grab the URL of the question
Go to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/
Select the blend file
Add the url of the question
Grab the url that results
Go back to the question and edit it

Add the new url to the bottom of the post

Comment: Okay, did it. Hope it helps.

Comment: I re-loaded it on my computer see if it makes a difference [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5608" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5608/)

Comment: on my computer it works on every axis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try clicking r (with your object selected) and press z,y, or x to rotate on that axis also the question seem a bit hard to understand can you upload a picture or try explaining you problem a bit better, hope you have success.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having this problem. I tried clicking r and it will lock rotation on the x axis. Then clicking r again allows free rotation on x and y axis. Cannot figure out how to get it to rotate only on the y axis though.

Update: Searching elsewhere I discovered others saying it's an issue for computers that do not have dedicated graphics cards. I do believe that may be the issue because I am currently on a work computer, which when queried, does indeed only have integrated graphics.